# How to include an abstract on a Part page?

Tags: chapters, parts

I want in Part I and an abstract on the same page (so I want make different part with different abstract, one abstract per part)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,final]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{P1}
\begin{abstract}
qsdpoqsidpoidpoqisdpoiqsdpo
\end{abstract}

\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

So I have try to use that (for style), but for the chapter it starts a new page and the style in table of content is not the best (same level to chapter)

```
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
      {\bfseries\Large}
      {\Huge{\filright\MakeUppercase{Partie} \thepart}}
      {1ex}
      {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
      [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

Thanks to campa, now I make that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,final]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setpartpreamble{
My context .}

\part{P1}


\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

It work very well, but another question how can I keep the same  part, chapter,section font in the report ?

Comment: Have you considered using the class `scrreprt`? It provides `\setpartpreamble` to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

The class `scrreprt` from the KOMA bundle provides a macro `\setpartpreamble` which allows you to put an abstract under the part title, as in

```
\setpartpreamble{%
\begin{abstract}
Some text.
\end{abstract}}
\part{Whatever}
```

Furthermore, if you give the class option `abstract=true` then the abstract will be preceded by the word "Abstract" (or whatever the content of `\abstractname` is).

If you want to keep the serif font of the standard classes you can put

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

in the preamble. The element `disposition` stands for

> all sectional unit titles, i. e., the arguments of `\part` down to
>   `\subparagraph` and `\minisec`, including the title of the abstract.

(From the KOMA documentation.)